# launch tmux from crontab with script

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron, tmux

I am having trouble launching tmux when executing a script through `sudo crontab -e`.

I am able to get it working ok when using this version:
`* * * * * tmux new -d -s test_instance`

However, this method with a script does not work:
`* * * * * /home/user/Desktop/run`

```
#!/bin/bash
tmux new -d -s test_instance
```

When using crontab with the script I do not see any new tmux instances in `sudo tmux ls`.

I've tried a few variants, such as:

- `sudo tmux new -d -s test_instance;`
- `/bin/tmux new -d -s test_instance`

Comment: (1) Is `/home/user/Desktop/run` executable? (2) Is the filesystem that holds the file FUSE, encrypted or in some other way "complicated"? (3) Why are you trying to run a regular user's file from the root's crontab? Without a good reason it's probably better to pick a user and stick to the choice. Also note the root's crontab is root's "personal" crontab. There's probably a system-wide crontab (`/etc/crontab` and related files) with slightly different syntax that allows running a job on behalf of any user.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
(1) Yes, I verified it is executable.
(2) I do not believe the filesystem is encrypted. I am running on Amazon Linux.
(3) The script does not run from the user crontab, I get an UNSAFE output in the cron log file.